# Non-Blocking Timer Tasks and Akka Actors

Tags: java, timer, akka

**Please note:** Although I'd *prefer* a solution using Akka's Java API (which is what I'm using), I'm happy with any working solution and can probably figure out how to translate Scala-based answers into Java-land.

---

I have an Akka app that has many actors, two of which are `Fizz` and `Buzz`. The `Fizz` actor can accept 2 types of messages:

- `StartNewTimerTask`; and
- `ResetAllTimerTasks`

The `Buzz` actor simply accepts a `DoItNow` message. The message flow between these actors and the rest of the system is as follows:

1. Anything (other actors, even event-driven components *outside* the actor system) can send `StartNewTimerTask` messages to the `Fizz` actor at any time
2. Each time the `Fizz` actor receives a `StartNewTimerTask` message, it creates and starts a new asynchronous/non-blocking timer that *attempts* to run for, say, 8 seconds. If the timer gets to the end (8 seconds) then a `DoItNow` message is sent to the `Buzz` actor
3. The `Fizz` actor can accept any number of concurrent `StartNewTimerTask` messages, and as such, can be "managing" potentially multiple timers at the same time, with each one counting towards that 8-second magical number. Hence if 20 other actors send `StartNewTimerTask` messages to the `Fizz` actor all within a few seconds of each other, then the `Fizz` actor would be "managing" 20 non-blocking, independent timers at the same time. And when each of those 20 timers reaches their respective 8-second duration, they send 20 independent `DoItNow` messages to the `Buzz` actor
4. When the `Fizz` actor receives a `ResetAllTimerTasks` message, *any* timers that are currently "in progress" will be interrupted/cancelled (so that they stop counting down to the 8-second duration, thus preventing them from sending a `DoItNow` message to `Buzz`). Hence, borrowing from our example above, if between times `t=1` and `t=3` the `Fizz` actor received 20 `StartNewTimerTask` messages, then at `t=10` perhaps 14 of their respective timers would have elapsed and fired `DoItNow` messages, and perhaps 6 would still be in progress. If at that exact moment `Fizz` received a `ResetAllTimerTasks` message, it would stop those 6 timers from elapsing and firing messages, and so in this example `Buzz` would only receive 14 `DoItNow` messages

I know that the Java 8 API (sans Akka) advocates extending `TimerTask` and submitting these tasks to the `Timer#scheduleAtFixedRate` method, but I'm not sure if that conflicts with Akka at all or if there is a better way to implement this functionality with the Akka API. My best attempt thus far:

```
// Groovy pseudo-code
class MyTimerTask extends TimerTask {
  @Inject
  ActorRef buzz

  @Override
  void run() {
    // No op!
  }

  void completeTask() {
    buzz.tell(new DoItNow(), null)
  }
}

class Fizz extends UntypedAbstractActor {
  @Inject
  Timer timer

  @Override
  void onReceive(Object message) {
    if(message in StartNewTimerTask) {
      timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new MyTimerTask(), 0, 8 * 1000)
    } else if(message in ResetAllTimerTasks) {
      timer.cancel()
    }
  }
}

class Buzz extends UntypedAbstractActor {
  @Override
  void onReceive(Object message) {
    if(message in DoItNow) {
      // Do something super cool now...
    }
  }
}
```

However I don't think I'm managing timers correctly or tapping into the full potential of the Akka scheduler/timer API. **Any thoughts?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider eschewing the Java `Timer` API in favor of the new [actor timer](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.5/java/actors.html#timers-scheduled-messages) functionality that was just released with Akka 2.5.4. Actor timers allow an actor to schedule periodic messages to itself with one or more internal timers that are tied to its lifecycle. To access this feature in Java, simply change the `Fizz` actor to extend [`AbstractActorWithTimers`](http://doc.akka.io/japi/akka/2.5/akka/actor/AbstractActorWithTimers.html).

The below example is in Scala (in Scala, mix in the [`Timers`](http://doc.akka.io/api/akka/2.5/akka/actor/Timers.html) trait):

```scala
object Fizz {
  private case object SendToBuzz
}

class Fizz(buzz: ActorRef) extends Actor with Timers {
  import Fizz._

  def receive = {
    case StartNewTimerTask =>
      val uuid = java.util.UUID.randomUUID
      timers.startPeriodicTimer(uuid, SendToBuzz, 8.seconds)
    case ResetAllTimerTasks =>
      timers.cancelAll()
    case SendToBuzz =>
      buzz ! DoItNow
  }
}
```

- When the `Fizz` actor processes a `StartNewTimerTask` message, it kicks off a new timer that will send a `SendToBuzz` message to `self` (that is, the `Fizz` actor) every eight seconds.
- When `Fizz` processes a `SendToBuzz` message, it sends a `DoItNow` message to the `Buzz` actor.
- When `Fizz` processes a `ResetAllTimerTasks` message, it cancels all the timers.
- If `Fizz` is restarted or stopped, all of its timers are automatically canceled.